# Smoothly change the player's speed when he leaves the zone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make `special zone` located on ground that `accelerates the player`, entering which the player's speed increases. When he gets out of it, the `speed smoothly returns to the original`. But now, when the player leaves the zone, the `speed instantly becomes the original`. Don't know how to realize it. Please help:)

My code:

**PlayerMovement**:

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidoby;
    public bool inZone = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (inZone == false)
        {
            _rigidoby.velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime) * 500;
        }
    }
```

**SpecialZone**:

```
private Vector3 _cachedVelocity;
    private Rigidbody _collisionRigidbody;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerMovement _player;

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        _player.inZone = true;

        if (_collisionRigidbody == null)
        {
            _collisionRigidbody = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            _cachedVelocity = _collisionRigidbody.velocity;
        }

        _collisionRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime) * 1000;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        _collisionRigidbody.velocity = _cachedVelocity;
        _player.inZone = false;
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for a formula to "smooth" the speed change, you could ask Math SE.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad I searched that I can use Lerp, but I can't think of where should I paste it

Comment: Unity has built in components that achieve similar effects - they are called Effectors. Their functionally is relatively limited but you can look if they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be to gradually decrease the speed in the update once you exit the trigger like this:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    //_collisionRigidbody.velocity = _cachedVelocity;
    _player.inZone = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (inZone == false)
    {
        _rigidoby.velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime) * 500;
    } else {
        If (_collisionRigidbody.velocity > _cachedVelocity;)
        _collisionRigidbody.velocity -= 0.01;
    }
}
```

Another could be to launch a coroutine when you exit the trigger.

Alternatively, you could use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) and set the percent of the speed change in the update like this:

```
Vector3 _startingSpeedBeforeDeceleration = Vector3.zero;
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    //_collisionRigidbody.velocity = _cachedVelocity;
    _startingSpeedBeforeDeceleration = _collisionRigidbody.velocity;
    _player.inZone = false;
}

float percent = 0f; //from 0 to 1
private void Update()
{
    if (inZone == false)
    {
        _rigidoby.velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime) * 500;
    } else {
        If (_collisionRigidbody.velocity > _cachedVelocity;) {
            _collisionRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(_startingSpeedBeforeDeceleration, _cachedVelocity, percent);
            percent += 0,01f;
        }
    }
}
```

Not debugged code. Note that I kept the departing speed in the variable `_startingSpeedBeforeDeceleration`, that is optional, and depends on the movement behaviour you want.
You can play around with `Vector3.Lerp` for example changing the first argument `_startingSpeedBeforeDeceleration` as a fixed value, and put there rigidbody speed every time it changes like this `Vector3.Lerp(_collisionRigidbody.velocity, _cachedVelocity, percent);`, that way you have a smooth start and smooth end, and a top speed change at the middle of the path. Also the `percent` change can be handled to set the movement behaviour.